# global static boolean pointer causes segmentation fault using pthread

Tags: c++, global-variables, pthreads, papi

New to pthread programming, and stuck on this error when working on a C++&C mixed code.

What I have done is to call the c code in the thread created by the c++ code. There is a static boolean pointer `is_center` used in the thread and should got free when the thread finishes.

However I noticed that every time when the program processed into the c function, the value of the boolean pointer would be changed and the segmentation fault then happened due to the free(). And the problem only happens when the c code is used. Remove the c code and the multi-thread c++ part works well.

Detail code is as follows:

```
static bool *is_center;

// omit other codes in between ...

void streamCluster( PStream* stream)
{
    // some code here ...
    while(1){
        // some code here ...
        is_center = (bool*)calloc(points.num,sizeof(bool));

        // start the parallel thread here.
        // the c code is invoked in this function.
        localSearch(&points,kmin, kmax,&kfinal); // parallel

        free(is_center);
    }
```

And the function using parallel is as follows (my c code is invoked in each thread):

```
void localSearch( Points* points, long kmin, long kmax, long* kfinal ) {
    pthread_barrier_t barrier;
    pthread_t* threads = new pthread_t[nproc];
    pkmedian_arg_t* arg = new pkmedian_arg_t[nproc];

    pthread_barrier_init(&barrier,NULL,nproc);

    for( int i = 0; i < nproc; i++ ) {
            arg[i].points = points;
            arg[i].kmin = kmin;
            arg[i].kmax = kmax;
            arg[i].pid = i;
            arg[i].kfinal = kfinal;
            arg[i].barrier = &barrier;

            pthread_create(threads+i,NULL,localSearchSub,(void*)&arg[i]);
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < nproc; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i],NULL);
    }

    delete[] threads;
    delete[] arg;
    pthread_barrier_destroy(&barrier);
}
```

Finally the function calling my c code:

```
void* localSearchSub(void* arg_) {                                                                                                                                                        

    int eventSet = PAPI_NULL;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    begin_papi_thread(&eventSet);                                                                                                                                                         

    pkmedian_arg_t* arg= (pkmedian_arg_t*)arg_;                                                                                                                                             
    pkmedian(arg->points,arg->kmin,arg->kmax,arg->kfinal,arg->pid,arg->barrier);                                                                                                            

    end_papi_thread(&eventSet);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

    return NULL;                                                                                                                                                                            
}
```

And from gdb, what I have got for the `is_center` is:

```
Breakpoint 2, localSearchSub (arg_=0x600000000000bc40) at streamcluster.cpp:1711
1711      end_papi_thread(&eventSet);
(gdb) s

Hardware watchpoint 1: is_center

Old value = (bool *) 0x600000000000bba0
New value = (bool *) 0xa93f3
0x400000000000d8d1 in localSearchSub (arg_=0x600000000000bc40) at streamcluster.cpp:1711
1711      end_papi_thread(&eventSet);
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Some new information about the code: for the c code, I am using the PAPI package. I write my own papi wrapper to initialize and read system counters. The code is as follows:

```
void begin_papi_thread(int* eventSet)                                                                                                                                                     
{                                                                                                                                                                                         
    int thread_id = pthread_self();                                                                                                                                                       
    // Events                                                                                                                                                                             
    if (PAPI_create_eventset(eventSet)) {                                                                                                                                                 
        PAPI_perror(return_value, error_string, PAPI_MAX_STR_LEN);                                                                                                                        
        printf("*** ERROR *** Failed to create event set for thread %d: %s\n.", thread_id, error_string);                                                                                 
    }                                                                                                                                                                                     
    if((return_value = PAPI_add_events(*eventSet, event_code, event_num)) != PAPI_OK)                                                                                                     
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        printf("*** ERROR *** Failed to add event for thread %d: %d.\n", thread_id, return_value);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    }                                                                                                                                                                                     
    // Start counting                                                                                                                                                                     
    if ((return_value = PAPI_start(*eventSet)) != PAPI_OK) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        PAPI_perror(return_value, error_string, PAPI_MAX_STR_LEN);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        printf("*** ERROR *** PAPI failed to start the event for thread %d: %s.\n", thread_id, error_string);
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
}  
void end_papi_thread(int* eventSet)                                                                                                                                                       
{                                                                                                                                                                                         
    int thread_id = pthread_self();                                                                                                                                                       
    int i;                                                                                                                                                                                

    long long * count_values = (long long*)malloc(sizeof(long long) * event_num);                                                                                                         
    if (PAPI_read(*eventSet, count_values) != PAPI_OK)                                                                                                                                    
        printf("*** ERROR *** Failed to load count values.\n");                                                                                                                           

    if (PAPI_stop(*eventSet, &dummy_values) != PAPI_OK) {
        PAPI_perror(return_value, error_string, PAPI_MAX_STR_LEN);
        printf("*** ERROR *** PAPI failed to stop the event for thread %d: %s.\n", thread_id, error_string);
        return;
    }
    if(PAPI_cleanup_eventset(*eventSet) != PAPI_OK)
        printf("*** ERROR *** Clean up failed for the thread %d.\n", thread_id);                                                                                                          
}
```

Comment: Not enough code. What's in the `localSearchSub()`? You are on the right track with watchpoints though. Look carefully at code around `streamcluster.cpp:1711`, check for array over/under-runs, any pointer manipulation. Try simplifying everything to the point where all steps are clearly visible.

Comment: The problem seems on the c code I used. I use PAPI api to capture the hardware counters in each thread, so I wrote a wrapper as above to initialize it and start the capture. 

I found that during my debugging, the address of `is_center` is changed after the `end_papi_thread` is called, and then the segmentation fault was triggered by `free(is_center)`. After I remove my papi wrapper code, everything works smoothly. 

So I was really confused by the update to the address. `free(is_center)` should work on the context of the main thread in my opinion, but it seems to be on the thread context...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you've posted enough code to really understand your problem, but it looks suspicious that you've declared `is_center` global. I assume you're using it in more than one place, possibly by multiple threads (`localSearchSub` mentions it, which is your worker thread function).

If `is_center` is being read or written by multiple threads, you probably want to protect it with a [pthread mutex](http://www.xgc.com/manuals/xgclib/x5257.html).  You say it is "freed when the thread finishes", but you should be aware that there are `nprocs` threads, and it looks like they're all working on an array of `is_center[points]` bools.  If `points != nproc`, this could b e a bad thing[1]. Each thread should probably work on its own array, and `localSearch` should aggregate the results.

The `xxx_papi_thread` functions don't get any hits on Google, so I can only imagine it's your own... unlikely we'll be able to help you, if the problem is in there :)

[1]: Even if `points == nproc`, it is not necessarily OK to write to different elements of an array from multiple threads (it's compiler and processor dependent).  Be safe, use a mutex.

Also, this is tagged `C++`.  Can you replace the `calloc` and dynamic arrays (using `new`) with `vector`s?  It might end up easier to debug, and it certainly ends up easier to maintain.  Why do you hate and want to punish the readers of your code? ;)

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks for your suggestions! I have posted more code and maybe you could have a look at them again?
Currently I think the problem should be on the global sharing of `is_center`. I think my c code doesn't have any influence on it, right? It may be from the multi-thread?

Comment: I'd guess yes, although the code you added doesn't seem to use it... so, I dunno :)  The papi_thread wrappers don't have any obvious mistakes (but I'm not familiar with the PAPI lib).  However, I found the code for `pkmedian` on Google code.  Are you defining `ENABLE_THREADS` when you compile?  It looks like it's necessary to use the barrier:  http://code.google.com/p/ua-gpu/source/browse/trunk/rodinia/openmp/streamcluster/streamcluster_omp.cpp?spec=svn227&r=227#771

Comment: Yes the threads are enabled. If I didn't misunderstand it, the pthread_barrier should work to isolate the write conflicts? By the way, the error only happens when I use the PAPI wrapper (the multi-thread works well with no wrapper)... Maybe still something wrong with the wrapper?